# ReactJS upload file to Express backend undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am trying to upload a profilePhoto from reactjs to express backend using FormData:

```
    const form = new FormData();
        form.append(user, "user");
     
        form.append(profilePhoto, "profilePhoto");
  axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8082/candidate/addCandidate",
      data: form,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
```

in the backend : (this works well with the postman and the image gets added to the backend)
const DIR = "./public/";

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-");
    cb(null, uuid() + "-" + fileName);
  },
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
      file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
      file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
      return cb(new Error("Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!"));
    }
  },
});

router.post(
  "/addCandidate",
  upload.single("profilePhoto"),
  (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");

    // try {
    const candidate = new Candidate({
      user: req.body.user,
      profilePhoto: url + "/public/" + req.file,
    });
    candidate
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbb", req);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "User registered successfully!",
          profilePhoto: result.profilePhoto,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaa", req.body.file);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
);
```

however, when ever i try to upload a file it doesnt get uploaded to the backend and i get `req.file undefined`. I tried to console the req and this is what i get body:
{'606aee02f057cd714db2b646': 'user',  '[object File]': 'profilePhoto'}

Any help!

Comment: I think you are misusing formData.append
It should be formData.append("key", value) so in your example:
form.append("user", user);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#example

Comment: @HaythemFarhat days struggling with this issue! you saved me. It worked

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, you can change it for your project

My component:

```
import React from "react";

import ConfigX from '../ConfigX'

class FileUploader extends React.Component
{

    url_upload   = "";
    url_download = "";  
    apiKey       = "";

    typ          = "news";
    typ_id       = 99999;

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = {          
           view: "list",
           title: "wybierz plik",
           files: [],                   
           uploadProcentAll: 10,                   
        }

        this.url_upload   = ConfigX.restApi + "/rest,file_upload";
        this.url_download = ConfigX.restApi + "/rest,file_list";  
        this.url_delete   = ConfigX.restApi + "/rest,file_delete";  
        this.apiKey       = this.props.apiKey;
        this.typ          = this.props.typ;
        this.typ_id       = this.props.typ_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get actual list of file uploaded to server
     */
    componentDidMount()
    {
            var dataPost = {

            };

            fetch( this.url_download , {
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(dataPost), 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                    'X-API-KEY': this.apiKey
                }
            })
            .then( res => res.json() )
            .then(json => {
                         
              //  this.setState({                 
              //      files: json
              //  });      
            
            });
    }

   
    onChangeInput(event)
    {
        var handle = event.target;
        
        console.log("FileUploader, selected: " + handle.files.length );

        if( handle.files.length == 0) return false;     
        
        
        for(var i = 0; i < handle.files.length; i++)  
        {  
            var file = handle.files[i];
            var isAdded = false;

            this.state.files.forEach( exFile => {
                 if(exFile.name == file['name']) isAdded = true;
            });

            if(isAdded) continue;

                var randName = crypto.getRandomValues( new Uint32Array(1)) + file['name'];

                var item = {
                    name: file['name'],                
                    progress: 0,
                    status: 'start',
                    uq: randName
                }
                var list = this.state.files;
                list.push(item);
                this.setState({ files: list});

                this.startUpload(file, list.length-1, randName );
        }        

    }

    onDelete(event)
    {
        var uq = event.target.getAttribute("uq");
        console.log("FileUploader, delete: " + uq);


        var dataPost = {
            uq: uq
        };

        fetch( this.url_delete , {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: JSON.stringify(dataPost), 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'X-API-KEY': this.apiKey
            }
        })
        .then( res => res.json() )
        .then(json => {
          
            if(json.status == "OK") //deleted on server..
            {
                var files = this.state.files.filter( item => {
                    if(item.uq == uq) return false;
                    return true;
                } );

                this.setState({
                    files: files
                })
            }
          
        });

    }

    refreshProgress()
    {
        var sumP   = 0;
        var countP = 0;

        this.state.files.map( item => {
            
                if(item.status == 'start' || item.status == 'upload')
                {
                    countP++;
                    sumP += item.progress;
                }

        } );

        var avg = sumP / countP;

        this.setState({
            uploadProcentAll: avg
        });
    }

    startUpload(file, tabIndex, randName)
    {        
        var refState = this.state;
        var refRefreshProgress = this.refreshProgress.bind(this);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();           
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(ev)
            {        
                var procent = (ev.loaded/ev.total );   
                procent *= 100;
                procent = Math.round(procent) ; 
                
                refState.files[tabIndex]['progress'] = procent;
                refState.files[tabIndex]['status'] = "upload";
                refRefreshProgress();
                
            }, false)


            xhr.addEventListener("load",  function(ev){               
            } , false);

            xhr.addEventListener("error", function(ev){}, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("abort", function(ev){}, false);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev)
            {                  
                  if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
                   {                                                                       
                      refState.files[tabIndex]['status'] = "finish";              
                      refState.files[tabIndex]['progress'] = 100;              
                   }
            };

            xhr.open('POST', this.url_upload, true);  
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', this.apiKey); 

            var data = new FormData();      
            data.append('file'+tabIndex, file ); 
            data.append('typ', this.typ);
            data.append('typ_id', this.typ_id);
            data.append('fileUploader','yes');
            data.append('uq', randName);
            xhr.send(data);

    }

    render()
    {        

        var progress = "";
        var progressStyle = {
            width: this.state.uploadProcentAll+"%"
        }

        if(this.state.uploadProcentAll > 0 && this.state.uploadProcentAll < 100 )
        {
            progress = (
                <div className="progressBar">
                   <div className="progressLine" style={progressStyle}>{this.state.uploadProcentAll}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="fileUploader">

                <div className="buttonUploader">
                   <input type="file" onchange="zaladuj_pliki(this)"  multiple id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]"  accept="*/*" onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)}  /> 
                   {progress}
                </div>

                <table>
                    {
                        this.state.files.map( (item,index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr  key={index}  >
                                    <td>{item.progress}</td>
                                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                                    <td uq={item.uq}   onClick={this.onDelete.bind(this) } >Del</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


export default FileUploader;
```

Put in parent:

```
  <FileUploader typ="sk_szkolenia" typ_id={this.state.rows.id} apiKey={this.props.apiKey} />
```